# Login informations validation VB.net

Tags: html, vb.net

How can i validate login information before logging in ? or "is it possible to validate login info ?"

Here's the code i use   :

```
  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").
                            SetAttribute("value", username.Text)
  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").
                            SetAttribute("value", password.Text)
  WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: Simple answer is **no**. Is there an API that you can use? It looks like you are probably just navigating to a website and automating through your code, this isn't a way to go if they offer an API...

Comment: @Zaggler its my website can i do something about it ?

Comment: You could create a service (php script) for example. Then you can make a web request to that script and send responses back to your calling application. I'm not sure what you have to work with, but having a service you can reach out to is the way to go.